# Is there a Python command that allows one to enter the logarithm of a function?

Tags: python, natural-logarithm

I'm writing some code to simulate a system of ODEs in Python and, as part of one of the ODEs, want to enter the natural logarithm of a function. However, I'm not able to find an appropriate way to do this, as it seems all the log/ln commands only work with numbers.

I've tried using math.log(x), np.log(x), and logn(e,x) while importing the necessary packages, but none of them seem to work.

```
#I've tried the following:
math.log(Amax/A)
np.log(Amax/A)
logn(e,Amax/A)
```

Comment: "none of them seem to work" is not specific enough. Please explain _how exactly_ these don't work for you.

Comment: These functions don't work for me since I am trying to take the logarithm of (Amax/A), where A is defined by an ODE. The examples I have given only apply to numbers and thus, I run into errors when trying to use them in my case. For example, I get the following error: TypeError: a float is required.

Comment: A is <class 'gekko.gk_variable.GKVariable'> and Amax is <class 'int'>. Casting it to a float doesn't work since the argument must be a string or a number, not a variable.

Comment: Before dealing with the logarithm, what can you do with `A`?  (`Amax` is just an integer.)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are asking for a new function that yields the logarithm of a previous function:

```
def log_of_f_maker(f):
    return lambda x: math.log(f(x))

log_of_sin = log_of_f_maker(math.sin)
```

This also assumes that function takes a single argument.

Comment: I have tried to use this function in my code as follows: log_of_f_maker(Amax/A) where A is a variable defined by an ODE. The code then returns to me the following error: Exception:  @error: Inequality Definition
 invalid inequalities: z > x < y
 $v3=(((((((((1-v5))*(0.011)))*(v3)))*(<functionlog_of_f_maker.<locals>.<lambda>
 at0x0dbe45d0>))-((((v6)*(0.012)))*(v3)))-((((0.058)*(v3)))*(v2)))
 STOPPING . . .

Comment: `Amax/A` is not a function; I'm not clear just what it is.